# How to insert the node comments form into quicktabs?

Tags: 7, views, comments, blocks

Im trying to insert node comments inside the quicktab, I can use views to list the comments and make the tab with it, but how to add the "Add comment" form to it ?

Comment: Another solution was to use [Panels Tabs](http://drupal.org/project/panels_tabs) module that suited perfectly. It adds Tabs style for styling Panels regions then in panels you can add node commetns with comment form and easily manage your context arguments. But for D7 it has some [issues](http://drupal.org/node/1484004) with IE 7 and 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a recipe for adding comments to a quicktab: http://www.katbailey.net/blog/go-forth-and-tabbify-quicktabs-30-drupal-7